# How to keep only main thread left after for...loop is finished during using OpenMP?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

My `OpenMP` program is like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(void){
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            sleep(30);
            printf("Exit loop\n");
        }

        sleep(40);

        return 0;
}
```

Run it and check threads:

```
# ./a.out &
[1] 26976
# ps -T 26976
  PID  SPID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
26976 26976 pts/0    Sl     0:00 ./a.out
26976 26977 pts/0    Sl     0:00 ./a.out
```

We can see for loop is expanded as `2` independent threads which are as expected. But after the loop is finished ("`Exit loop`" is printed), I find there are still `2` threads:

```
# Exit loop
Exit loop
ps -T 26976
  PID  SPID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
26976 26976 pts/0    Sl     0:00 ./a.out
26976 26977 pts/0    Sl     0:00 ./a.out
```

From my intuition, I think only main thread should be left, and other threads should vanish. Is there any approach to achieve this effect?

Comment: This is implementation specific. Which OpenMP runtime (compiler) are you using?

Comment: @Zulan: `gcc 6.3.1`.

Comment: As Zulan pointed out, this is implementation​ specific. Many implementations keep threads alive (but idling) to avoid creation and destruction costs each time a parallel region is found.

Comment: Most implementations use thread pools both for efficiency and in order to comply with a specific part of the OpenMP standard concerning the values of thread-private variables. If that bothers you, use Pthreads instead.